# How do I show everyday availability through the SF Calendar?

Tags: calendar

My work day starts at 09:30 and ends at 20:00.

And I thought that by editing my "Start of Day" and "End of Day" settings to reflect this, other users would be able to see my Calendar and know that I wouldn't be available until 09:30 or past 20:00, everyday.

As it turns out, they can't - how they see other people's Calendars depends on their SoD and EoD settings, rather than the SoD and EoD settings of the person whose Calendar they are viewing. So if their day starts at 07:00 and ends at 22:00, they will see my Calendar and think I may be available at 21:00.

Am I completely mistaken, or is there any way to get around this? I've used recurring events before ("ESil is not available between the hours of 20:00 and 00:00"), but that's rather messy and inefficient.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible using the standard calendar views. It does seem like a good candidate for the [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideasearch).

Comment: The IdeaExchange site URL is now moved to https://ideas.salesforce.com/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of posting this to the Idea Exchange on your behalf. Feel free to add any important points that I missed.

> ## [Show users start of day and end of day when viewing a shared calendar](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cMnSQAU)
>
> When viewing a shared calendar, show the calender owners start of day and end of day times.
>
> This would be useful so that events can be created to fall within their working day.
>
> Also, when checking availabitliy for a new evert, notify if the times fall outside the users start/end of day.

Comment: Thanks! But may I suggest these changes?  *When we´re viewing a shared calendar, show us the calendar owner´s start of day and end of day times. This would be useful because events could be created to fall within their working day. Also, when checking availability for a new event, notify us if the times fall outside of their start/end of day times.

Comment: @ESil Unfortunately the content of an idea can't be amended once posted. Feel free to post that as a comment on the idea.